# ASP.net Listview EditTemplate Hide/Show Options by Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview which has an ItemTemplate and EditTemplate. When I switch an item into edit mode I have a bunch of checkboxes as options. Now the problem.

in Editmode I would like to have certain options disappear (or replaced by "--") when certain checkboxes are unchecked and of course reappear when it is check again.

I have tried to use the OnCheckedChanged event in the edittemplate but it doesn't fire. since I see no other useful events to react to that could do this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set AutoPostback="true" on your checkboxes? The OnCheckedChanged event won't do anything unless this is set.

Comment: I should really slap myself for that one.